# Randomly Assign People to Tasks

Tags: code-golf, array

The challenge is to assign people to tasks randomly~.
From stdin you get 2 lines. Line one is a comma-separated list of names. Line 2 is a comma-separated list of jobs.
The output required is one line per task person combo.
The line should be formatted as Name:task.
If there are not enough people for jobs or vice verse then they will not be output.

~ Randomly is defined as each run with the same input has a reasonably different output.

Example Input:

```
Bob,John,Susan,Josie,Kim,Tom
Bins,Floor,Windows
```

Example Output:

```
Bob:Windows
Susan:Bins
Kim:Floor
```

Comment: Can there be only two possible outputs?

Comment: Also, usually we don't like to restrict on the input format.

Comment: @KennyLau what makes you think there could only be two possible outputs?

Comment: @KennyLau Also, sorry about specifying the input format, I actually don't care just thought I should specify something. I am used to stack overflow being really precise about the details provide for questions assumed it might extend here :)

Comment: I mean, can we randomly choose one from only 2 possible outputs?

Comment: Is the output format strict? Or would something like ['Bob', 'Windows'] be okay?

Answer (score 3):

### 05AB1E, 7 bytes

**Code:**

```
.r².r)ø
```

[Try it online](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=LnLCsi5yKcO4&input=WyJCb2IiLCJKb2huIiwiU3VzYW4iLCJKb3NpZSIsIktpbSIsIlRvbSJdClsiQmlucyIsIkZsb29yIiwiV2luZG93cyJd)

**Following the input/output spec strictly (16 bytes):**

```
.r².r)øvy`r?':?,
```

**Explained:**

```
.r                # radomize first input
  ².r             # randomize second input
     )ø           # merge the lists to an array of pairs cutting out extras
       vy`r?':?,  # format output
```

[Try it online](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=LnLCsi5yKcO4dnlgcj8nOj8s&input=WyJCb2IiLCJKb2huIiwiU3VzYW4iLCJKb3NpZSIsIktpbSIsIlRvbSJdClsiQmlucyIsIkZsb29yIiwiV2luZG93cyJd)

Answer (score 2):

## Java 7, <s>240</s> <s>239</s> 238 bytes

```
import java.util.*;class M{public static void main(String[]a){String[]p=a[0].split(",");List j=new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(a[1].split(",")));for(int i=0;j.size()>0;)System.out.println(p[i++]+":"+j.remove((int)(Math.random()*j.size())));}}
```

Can most likely be golfed more with some arrays magic, instead of `List j=new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(a[1].split(",")));`..

**Ungolfed:**

[Try it here](https://ideone.com/XTygsY)

```
import java.util.*;

class M{
    public static void main(String[] a){
        String[] p = a[0].split(",");
        List j = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(a[1].split(",")));
        for(int i = 0; j.size() > 0;){
            System.out.println(p[i++] + ":" + j.remove((int)(Math.random() * j.size())));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 6 bytes

```
CmO.pd
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=CmO.pd&input=%5B%5B%27Bob%27%2C+%27John%27%2C+%27Susan%27%2C+%27Josie%27%2C+%27Kim%27%2C+%27Tom%27%5D%2C+%5B%27Bins%27%2C+%27Floor%27%2C+%27Windows%27%5D%5D&debug=0)

#### How it works:

```
CmO.pd
        (implicitly) takes the evaluated input
 m   d  for each "line":
   .p       generate all permutations
  O         choose one randomly
C       truncating transpose
```

## Following strictly the input/output format:

(16 bytes)

```
jjL\:CmO.pcd\,.z
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=jjL%5C%3ACmO.pcd%5C%2C.z&input=Bob%2CJohn%2CSusan%2CJosie%2CKim%2CTom%0ABins%2CFloor%2CWindows&debug=0)

#### How it works:

```
jjL\:CmO.pcd\,.z
              .z  takes all lines
      m    d      for each line:
          c \,        split by ","
        .p            generate all permutations
       O              choose one randomly
     C            truncating transpose
 jL\:             join every pair by ":"
j                 join all pairs by newlines
```

Comment: Realy nice, I have only ever done golf in python, I should learn pyth

Comment: The last edit seems to break the random on each run part. but still cool :), ohh you updated again nvm

Comment: This edit should be random.

Answer (score 1):

## Jelly, 13 bytes

```
Œ!€X€ZL’$ÐfŒṘ
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=xZIh4oKsWOKCrFpM4oCZJMOQZsWS4bmY&input=&args=W1snQm9iJywgJ0pvaG4nLCAnU3VzYW4nLCAnSm9zaWUnLCAnS2ltJywgJ1RvbSddLCBbJ0JpbnMnLCAnRmxvb3InLCAnV2luZG93cyddXQ)

Answer (score 1):

## Mathcad, [tbd] bytes

[image]

csort(M,n) sorts matrix M on column n.
augment joins two arrays columnwise.
runif(n,a,b) returns a vector of n uniformly-distributed numbers over the range a..b.
concat(a,b) concatenates strings a and b.

With due apologies to Messrs Gilbert and Sullivan.

---

Mathcad scoring system yet to be determined (must get round to posting something on Meta ...).  However, this solution clearly wouldn't be a contender for anything other than a Programming Language specific leaderboard.   Taking a rough keyboard equivalence, and noting that Mathcad uses keyboard shortcuts for entering programming and some other operators, it takes around 100 "bytes".

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript (Firefox 30-57), 82 bytes

```
(a,b,s=a=>a.sort(_=>Math.random()-.5),c=s(b))=>[for(x of s(a))if(c[0])[x,c.pop()]]
```

Uses bogus sort to shuffle. Version which accepts two string parameters of comma-separated names and returns lines of colon-separated matchups for 110 bytes, where `\n` represents the literal newline character:

```
(a,b,s=a=>a.sort(_=>Math.random()-.5),c=s(b.split`,`))=>[for(x of s(a.split`,`))if(c[0])x+':'+c.pop()].join`\n`
```

Answer (score 0):

### Q, 38 Bytes

```
t:{$[n:&/#:'x:{(-#x)?x}'x;+n#/:x;0N]}
```

NOTE.- input and output format not exactly as proposed (see test)

**Test**

```
."\\S ",$7h$.z.t    /To accomplish a random output we mofify seed based on internal clock
t(`Bob`John`Susan`Josie`Kim`Tom; `Bins`Floor`Windows)
/generates (`Susan`Windows;`Kim`Bins;`John`Floor) (a different result each run)
```

**Explanation**

`(-seqLen)?seq` Shuffles the sequence

`x:{(-#x)?x}'x` shuffles each sequence of x (argument with sequence of names and sequence of works) and reassign to x

`n:&/#:'x` Assigns to n the minimum over (&/) each sequence lengths (#:'x)

`$[n;+n#/:x;0N]` If n (if n is not 0), executes flip n take of each seq, Else returns null

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 69 bytes

```
n=gets.split(/,|\n/).shuffle;puts gets.split(',').map{|j|n.pop+':'+j}
```

**Ungolfed:**

```
names = gets.split(/,|\n/).shuffle
jobs = gets.split(',')
jobs.each do |job|
    name = names.pop
    puts "#{name}:#{job}"
end
```